# I want to implement a layout that pops from the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to implement a layout that pops from the bottom and covers half of screen behind it. How do i do it? Is there any library that does it out of the box? I want to do like something shown in the image below.
[image]

Comment: search for `bottom sheet android` on google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Design idea](https://material.io/design/components/sheets-bottom.html#behavior) first. And if feeling lazy, there is plenty of libraries to do this, for example [this](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet)